# Windows Mail on old laptop to new Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail, windows-mail

I just got a new laptop with Windows 7.  I use Windows Mail on my old (Vista) laptop.  I have four years of emails (and attachments) organized into many folders.  My hope is to get all of that onto the new computer without losing anything--emails, attachments, folder organization.  I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

I do not know how to do this best.  Windows 7 does not have Windows Mail that works, although I have found some information on trying to make it work.  It involves a lot of steps that I don't entirely understand and there is a web site that instructs you to download things that I am worried could be dangerous.

The options I have found are to try to get Windows Mail on my Windows 7 computer or to upgrade the Vista system to Windows Live Mail.

**My specific questions are:**

1. Is there a best way to get all emails, attachments, and folder organization from Windows Mail on Vista to my new Windows 7 laptop?  I like using Windows Mail because I know how it works but a open to something else.
2. What do I need to know to try to get this to work through getting Windows Mail onto Windows 7?
3. Would downloading Windows Live Mail onto the Vista laptop allow me to seamlessly transfer all emails, attachments, and folder organization from Window Mail?  Then how would I transfer all this to the Windows 7 laptop?
4. Is there some other option I haven't found?

I purchased PC Mover from LapLink to move things to the new computer and have the included ethernet cable.  I tried to move files, setting, and programs (including Windows Mail) and it didn't work. I "undid" the transfer waiting to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Windows 7 Easy Transfer tool and see if that gives you what you need.  It's under Accessories/System Tools.

Comment: I purchased PC Mover to move things from the old to new computer.  Is the Easy Transfer the same?

Comment: Easy Transfer is the Microsoft tool for moving stuff from old to new.  You can try it without making any changes and see if it suits what you're after.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer Vista will already have it but it's not the correct version.  This link should help.  As for the programs... you are simply best off installing them... don't rely on any transfer to move those over and do that first, THEN move your stuff.